# Facebook Graph API publish post with multiple attachments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

I am trying to publish post to Facebook news feed (timeline) with Graph API.

I can use Facebook standard GUI messenger to publish post and add photos to this post. But how to make this from Facebook Graph API?

I can upload images to album and try to create link on this images. But can create only 1 link.

What is the correct algorithm to publish post with more than 1 picture added to this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now it is not possible to publish one post with multiple pictures. You need to create separate posts for each one of them, or put all the images together in one with your favourite server language and post it as single picture.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can upload a multi story photo(I did it using Graph Api and PHP) but the problem comes if you need scheduled this post.Your post is schedule but also it shows on the page's feed.

P.S. I'm using Graph Api v2.9

PHP Code

```
$endpoint = "/".$page_id."/photos";

foreach ($multiple_photos as $file_url):
array_push($photos, $fb->request('POST',$endpoint,['url' =>$file_url,'published' => FALSE,]));
endforeach;

$uploaded_photos = $fb->sendBatchRequest($photos,  $page_access_token); 

foreach ($uploaded_photos as $photo):
array_push($data_post['attached_media'], '{"media_fbid":"'.$photo->getDecodedBody()['id'].'"}');
endforeach;

$data_post['message'] = $linkData['caption'];

$data_post['published'] = FALSE;

$data_post['scheduled_publish_time'] = $scheduled_publish_time;

$response = $fb->sendRequest('POST', "/".$page_id."/feed", $data_post, $page_access_token);

$post_id = $cresponse->getGraphNode()['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it is possible to do so: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#publishing-a-multi-photo-story

The gist is to:

1. Upload photos but mark them as "unpublished", keep the ids
2. Create a "post" with those "unpublihsed" photos as attachments

Hope it helps.